# GeoDistance filter ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using the [Geo Distance Filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/geo-distance-filter.html) with [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org). The queries work fine, but I am wondering if it is possible to obtain the distance calculated for each document. For example, if I set a distance threshold at 100km, I'd like to obtain the distance for each document:

**doc1**: `24 km` << 100km

**doc2**: `12 km` << 100km

...

**Is this possible and how?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I believe it's possible, but when I tried, I couldn't make it work (I'm using Tire, a RoR gem, so you might have better luck with just ElasticSearch).

Take a look at this issue: https://github.com/karmi/tire/issues/169

I, `niuage`, is asking the same question there.

First, I think that you have to sort by distance.
Then the distance should be in the `_score` field, but for some reason, it wasn't for me.

I looked at the doc and found `track_scores`:

`When sorting on a field, scores are not computed.
By setting track_scores to true, scores will still be computed and tracked.`

So you might want to try to set `track_scores` to true, and look at your `_score` field.

Comment: Thanks so much @Robin. Just a thought for your problem: I am using the [Spherical Law of Cosines](http://sgowtham.net/blog/2009/08/04/php-calculating-distance-between-two-locations-given-their-gps-coordinates/) to calculate the distances at the moment. The function is super easy to implement. By working with a threshold, I found out that the distance computed for the search is this exact formula, so it might be a good idea to use this if you can't find the distance in `_score`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually using the Haversine formula, which your article also talks about. But I use it for something else which runs in a background job, I didn't want to have to compute this stuff again when I display the results. I could do it in javascript I guess. Or just investigate further, I'm sure there is way to do it with elastic/tire.

Comment: Sure. I'll try what your suggest and will keep you updated. Many thanks. +1 for `sort` and `_score`.